# How to automatically create database tables and schema with Flask and Sqalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a small Flask application. I add an extra security layer which is log in. I based my refactoring on the [DO article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login).

In a nutshell,

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'e56432f4402c9a0c166fe6c6a0a2fbbd'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

        # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    return app
```

In order to create DB, I need to run in REPL:

```
  from project import db, create_app
  db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

This is both inconvenient and makes Docker image creation harder. I run an application as `flask run`. I saw similar issues but don't understand how to apply to my scenario.

How can I overcome this complication?

UPDATE 1:

My project structure is the following:

```
project/
  project/
    __init__.py
    auth.py
    main.py
    models.py
    static/
    templates/
  Dockerfile
  requirements.txt
```

Comment: Do you have a repository about this project of yours? I'm facing the same problem already, you were the one that got close to it. I'm also following the Digital Ocean tutorial.

Comment: Hi, @GuilhermeMatheus, I still have access to the project. Unfortunately, it is closed-source, so I cannot post a link to it. Do you have any particular questions?

Comment: Hi @Dmytro Chasovskyi, thank you anyway for asking. How can I run the `db.create_all()` from __init__.py file? Because the solution you propose (it worked for me) is in a function. I droped the tables that flask created and now I don't how to create again.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus I added a comment to my answer. I guess your problem that you are running the app via python, in the meantime you need to run it via flask utility.

Comment: thank you for the support! It really helped me. I deploy my app to Heroku. Repository: https://github.com/guimatheus92/Game-Recommendation-System. Heroku: https://recommendation-game-system.herokuapp.com/. Medium: https://guimatheus92.medium.com/game-recommendation-system-using-machine-learning-and-flask-e0c2a3e0305b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a more elegant solution

Instead of `return app` make the following block, so an application will be created in the runtime if and only if the context was initialized and database created.

```
with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        return app
```

Surprisingly the `Flask-SqlAlchemy` is pointing out to REPL db creation as a first solution, not the one above.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV FLASK_APP=.

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
```

The catch is that you have to change how you run `flask`, not via `python` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the database to be created when you run the flask app:

I would put this code

```
def createMyDatabase():
    from project import db, create_app
    db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

into the file `makedatabase.py` and save it into your program's root directory. Then add `from <path to makedatabase.py>/makedatabase import createMyDatabase` to the top of your `__init__.py` file and then just after your import statements in `__init__.py` write `createMyDatabase()`. I think that this would be the easiest way to do it in your situation.

If you don't want the database to be created every time that you run the program:

You could just take the function out of the `makedatabase.py` file and then run the file just as it is before you run the flask application.

Comment: Hm, I added my project structure, so express what I tried to do more explicitly. I added makedatabase.py to the upmost `project` and run the application but I still get broken imports. Do you know how to debug it further?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The import should be `from <path to the file relative to __init__.py including file eg. myapp/makedatabase> import createMyDatabase`. That should solve your import error. Then you should be able to just call the function `createMyDatabase()` to create the db.